# Change separator's color and icon's color on tableview

Tags: iphone, uitableview, ios7, tableview

i'm transitioning my app to ios7, but i really don't understand some things. For example, my sidemenu (like facebook's menu) has different separator for selected item. Why?
in second hand, the iconof this menu was in a white png, why in my app they are drawed gray?

[image: example of ios7 bad menu]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

make your table view CellSeparatorStyleNone like

```
[yourTableView setSeparatorStyle:UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone];
```

and design your custom cell with separator like [image]

Comment: Thanks.Then i've to create a xib file for table raw?

Comment: No it's not mandatory. If you are designing your cell via coding then add the separator image via coding and if you are designing your cell  via xib then go for it. Concept is you have to add an image for separator. :)

Comment: Very thanks. And for thw problem of images that'isnt white but gray as in the image?